# How to call API using AJAX in Spring 4

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

Below what i have already Tried is:

**In Jsp Page:**

```
<select name="batch" id="batch" class="form-control" onchange="getCourse()" >
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${batchList}">
        value="${item.key}">${item.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function getCourse(){
            $batch = $('#batch');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "./batchajax?batchId="+$batch.attr("selectedIndex"),

                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("SUCCESS ", data);
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        console.log("ERROR ", e);
                    }

            });

        }
</script>
```

- If we select any option from drop down list it should call API on onChange() event of drop down list.
- It will call getCourse() function and i get below message on console at server side.

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI **[/ABCD/admin/batchajax]** in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

For this API, Spring controller is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AjaxController {

 @RequestMapping(value="/batchAjax",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getBatch(@RequestParam(value = "batchId", required = true)String batchId) {
     String returnText;
     System.out.println("batchId from ajax is" );

     return new ResponseEntity<String>("batchId from ajax is", HttpStatus.OK);
 }

}
```

If I run this API from the browser it runs well. Below is screenshot

[image]

I am not getting where i am doing wrong.

Can Anyone make me correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring mvc request mappings are case sensitive. You have to change your ajax request from,

`url: "./batchajax?batchId="+$batch.attr("selectedIndex")`

to
 `url: "./batchAjax?batchId="+$batch.attr("selectedIndex")`

Comment: thank you so much. i did such a silly mistake. You save my time. Its work for me now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `url: "./batchajax?batchId="+$batch.attr("selectedIndex"),`
to `url: "admin/batchAjax?batchId="+$batch.attr("selectedIndex"),`

you declare controller `@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")` so you need to access your controller first `admin` then your method `/batchAjax`.

also careful about case sensitive word you use this `batchajax` but your Method declare `batchAjax`.